# Hibernate Envers: Retrieve revision type deleted entries

Tags: hibernate-envers

```
AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery()
                     .forRevisionsOfEntity(AB.class, false, true)
                     .add(AuditEntity.property("bId").eq(bId))
                     .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
```

The above code retrieves all revisions except RevType `DEL` revisions as `bId` column is `null`.

I have three Tables `A`, `B`, and `AB`. `AB` table is a relationship table. So `AB` table has `abID` as PK, and `aId`, `bID`, Revision Info. Whenever `B` is deleted, it updates `AB_AUDv table with revtype`DEL`and keeps`aid`,`bid`as`null`.

To display the deleted `B`, can anyone suggest me with a modified auditreader query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either:

- store data at delete time ([Envers docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d0e4871), `org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete`)
- query for the entity at the (revision it was deleted at) - 1.

Comment: Thanks adamw, where should I annotate the  org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true,

Comment: I found it , I ve added it to hibernateproperties in applicationcontext-hibernate.xml